# Creación de archivos y escritura en C#

Tags: c#, archivo, filewriter

Escribí la siguiente clase para crear un archivo con un formato en específico (.rmap):

```
public class Creator{
string FolderPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string FileName = "";

public Creator(){
    FolderPath += "SavedData";

    var src = DateTime.Now;
    FileName = src.Day + src.Month + src.Year + "_" + src.Hour + src.Minute + src.Millisecond + ".rmap";

    CreateFile(FolderPath, FileName);
}

public void CreateFile(String folder, String file){
    Debug.Log(folder + "\n" + file);
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(folder + file)){
        Debug.Log("new archive");
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(folder + file)){
            // folder path
            byte[] infoPath = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(FolderPath);
            fs.Write(infoPath, 0, infoPath.Length);
            Debug.Log("path writed");

            // folder name
            byte[] infoName = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(FileName);
            fs.Write(infoName, 0, infoName.Length);
            Debug.Log("name writed");
        }
    }else{
        Debug.Log("File \"" + (folder + file) + "\" already exists.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Pero al ir a la ruta donde supuestamente se guarda el archivo, no aparece, considero que no se crea.

¿Qué puede estar fallando en mi código? La carpeta "SavedData" si existe en ese directorio y las cadenas que quiero escribir al archivo son la ruta y el nombre del mismo, los mensajes en el Log si aparecen, pero el archivo no se crea...

El ejemplo que estoy siguiendo es el siguiente:
[enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-create-a-file-or-folder)

Comment: pero no estas mandando a crear nada en esa carpeta.. tu proceso CreateFile recibe un nombre de carpeta y un archivo... que no se a donde van a parar...

Answer (score 0):

El método `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` devuelve la ruta sin el último separador.

Al concatenarle `FolderPath += "SavedData";` estás asumiendo la presencia del `\` al final y al no estar posiblemente estás generando otras carpetas en un nivel superior.

Siempre que trabajes con carpetas, lo mejor es utilizar `System.IO.Path.Combine()` tal como lo hacen en el ejemplo al que haces referencia.

Modifica en el contructor de la clase la siguiente línea:

```
public Creator()
{
    FolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderPath, "SavedData");

    //...    
}
```